# Do we need the tag [effectiveness]?

Tags: discussion, tags

A few questions have been on the form of "how effective is it to..." and that lead to the creation of the tag [effectiveness](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/effectiveness).

I think that *effectiveness* is quite vague. And that most the question relying on it should probably be closed. But having a tag, somehow implies that the other question **are not** looking to be effective?

What are your views?

Answer (score 6):

First, let me state that I'm assuming that [effectiveness](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/effectiveness) is asking for an evaluation of the effectiveness of something. As such, it will pretty much always be a subset of [learning-methods](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning-methods). If it should mean something else, then disregard the rest of my post.

And indeed, 7 of the 10 current questions tagged with [effectiveness](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/effectiveness) are also tagged [learning-methods](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning-methods). And of the remaining 3, one ought to be tagged [learning-methods](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning-methods), and the other two have really nothing to do with effectiveness anyway.

Of our 38 [learning-methods](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning-methods) questions, 7 are tagged [effectiveness](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/effectiveness) and an additional 13 *could* (should?) be tagged [effectiveness](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/effectiveness)

This means 52% of our [learning-methods](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning-methods) questions are also effectively (pun intended?) about [effectiveness](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/effectiveness).

And as I look at these questions, I'm not sure that [effectiveness](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/effectiveness) really adds much value to them.

Let me offer some examples:

- [Why are flash cards effective in learning a language?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/44/13)
- [Can practicing vocabulary from L2 to the same L2 instead of from L2 to L1 be more effective for learning the vocabulary?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/5/13)
- [What are the benefits or drawbacks of learning poetry?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/251/13)

Do these items need a tag to indicate they are asking for an evaluation?

I think I can see a case for a tag to mark these questions, but [effectiveness](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/effectiveness) doesn't feel right to me.

I think I would suggest something along the lines of [benefit-analysis](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/benefit-analysis), but am open to other options.

Comment: Late to the game, but `effectiveness` is not necessarily about learning methods; it can also be about teaching methods. (However, some - more recent - questions are unclear on whether they are about learning or teaching.)

Answer (score -1):

Aren't the nature of asking questions and searching for answers the way to improve effectiveness? Being said that, every question has a hidden [effectiveness](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/effectiveness) tag. We don't need another one.

Comment: No. Absolutely not. Many questions aren't about effectiveness at all. Three recent examples: [1](http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/326/13), [2](http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/309/13), [3](http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/308/13).